# How to build a social bar and to position it's buttons?

Tags: css, html, xhtml

I'm trying to build a basic bar that contains 5 buttons, every button is consist of an icon and below text that describes the icon.
I want that all the images will be on the same line and the descriptions will be underneath.

```
    <a href="tel:036781223333" title ="call us"><img src=phone.png />call office </a>
<a href= "http://www.bgasgdhen.com/" title = "website"><img src=circle.png />link to website </a>
<a href= "advbagsgadron.vcf" title = "add to contacts"><img src=book.png />add to contacts </a>
```

in this code for example, "call office" should be below the first img, "link to website" below the second and so on but it writes the description but the description appears in the same line with the icons, every description next to itws icon.
can you help?
thx

Comment: First off, those should be in a list, and then you should put a `<br>` after the `<img>`-tag.

Comment: Please try adding more information. This may include what you have tried already and what has / has not worked as well as any other information that may help someone answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:
The icons/links are placed in a list, the HTML is cleaned up, and I've added a bit of CSS to show how it can look

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  }
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
  }
li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  }
li a img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="tel:036781223333" title="call us"><img src=phone.png><br>call office</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.bgasgdhen.com/" title="website"><img src=circle.png><br>link to website</a></li>
<li><a href="advbagsgadron.vcf" title="add to contacts"><img src=book.png><br>add to contacts</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the HTML as well. Put just the text in there, because the images have no semantic value. Using CSS you can show the icons, and you don't even need an element for that. Just use the `::before` pseudo-element.

```css
nav.social {
  text-align: center;
}
nav.social a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}
nav.social a::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 32px;
  background: url(http://www.phonebook.com/favicon.ico) top center no-repeat;
}
nav.social a.website::before {
  background-image: url(http://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico);
}
nav.social a.vcard::before {
  background-image: url(https://en.wikipedia.org/favicon.ico);
}
```

```html
<nav class="social">
  <a class="phone" href="tel:036781223333" title="call us">call office</a>
  <a class="website" href="http://www.bgasgdhen.com/" title="website">link to website </a>
  <a class="vcard" href="advbagsgadron.vcf" title="add to contacts">add to contacts </a>
</nav>
```